# Is there a way to code a result list within a cell in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Given that I have a list of item serial number, together with their expiry dates.

Is there a way code in excel, to generate the serial numbers that I want into a cell, like this example below,

"Serial 1, serial 2, serial 3... "

Comment: If you have access to `TEXTJOIN` it will be rather simple. However your question is quite vague and untill you provide us with a [mcve] it's not clear what exactly your are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sample data and expected output will help. Also please show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple user-defined function in VBA if you don't have access to `TEXTJOIN` (which I don't as well):

```
Public Function customConcat(rng As Range, delim As String) As String
Dim cll As Range
For Each cll In rng
    If customConcat = vbNullString Then
        customConcat = cll.Value
    Else
        customConcat = customConcat & delim & cll.Value
    End If
Next cll
End Function
```

This function will allow you to select a range and define a delimiter to put between the values. In your case you would use `", "` as a delimiter.